# How to auto increment a column using an Entity Framework core in memory database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am using an in memory EF Core database like this:

```
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DmpContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase("test")
            .Options;

        var context = new CustomContext(options);
```

I am adding some random data using Bogus.

```
            var resources = new Faker<Resource>()
            .RuleFor(x => x.Name, x => x.Name.FullName())
            .Generate(20);
```

In this resources collection all the ids are still zero.

When I execute the AddRange I would expect the ids to be generated:

```
                context.Resources.AddRange(resources);
                context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But they are not generated.

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The instance of entity type 'Resource' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ResourceId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

So I thought, then let me just set them and make an auto increment mechanism myself. That worked.

However when I then try and test my `Add` methods (these methods insert records). I am not able to set the IDs in these methods, since the ID is not even in the interface. Again I would expect EF to auto generate the ID but it tries to insert ID 1 (which is already taken, because I already have generated ID 1 until 20).

**Does anyone know how to tell an EF core in memory database to always auto increment it's keys?**

Comment: EF Core does auto increment keys which are set up to do so regardless of using in memory or normal database. Consider providing full repro (a.k.a `mcve`) because the issue cannot be reproduced with the currently provided information - after calling `AddRange` the `Id`s are auto generated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? My implementation works for SQL, etc. but is not working for the in-mem database.

Answer (score 2):

In the in-memory database, EF can't detect the identity property of an entity, I have overridden

> InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator

class for handling this problem. The below code shows how to do that.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
}

public class RoleResource : BaseEntity
{
    public long RoleID { get; set; }
    public long ResourceID { get; set; }
}

public class CASDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CASDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<RoleResource> RoleResources { get; set; }
}


public class CustomInMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<TEntity> 
: InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<long> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    private long _current;
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;
    public override long Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        long result;
        if (entry.Properties.Any(x => x.Metadata.ValueGenerated == ValueGenerated.OnAdd))
        {
            _current = entry.Context.Set<TEntity>()
                                    .Select(x => x.ID)
                                    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                                    .Max(x => x);
            var res = Interlocked.Increment(ref _current);
            result = res;
        }
        else
            result = base.Next(entry);
        return result;
    }
}
public class InMemoryDbContext : CASDbContext
{
    public InMemoryDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleResource>(rr =>
        {
            rr.HasKey(e => e.ID);
            rr.Property(e => e.ID)
           .HasValueGenerator<CustomInMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<RoleResource>>();
        });
    }
}

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        srvCollection.AddScoped<SeedData>();
        srvCollection.AddTransient<CASDbContext, InMemoryDbContext>();
        srvCollection.AddDbContext<InMemoryDbContext>(x => 
          x.UseInMemoryDatabase("In-Memory")).AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase();

        _serviceProvider = srvCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    }
/* The packages version
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.2.6" />
*/
```

Answer (score -5):

You should mark the identity field in the entity framework designer or in code as Identity. EF manages all the identity generation mechanism by itself.

Check [this resource](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute)

This is how you set it in the editor (press f4 or right click->properties on the identity field):

[image]

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question. This is about an in memory database using EF core, nor does it help to set the store generated pattern to Identity for an in memory database.

Comment: @NickN. Oh sorry. Can You add the object model you are trying to add to the question (Faker and Resource)?

Comment: The Faker is just a helper that returns an IEnumerable of Resources. A resource is just an Id (int) and a Name (string)

Comment: @NickN. shouldn't rulefor/generate be on the id and not on the name?

Comment: I tried that as well, seems to be working. However then the next time I add a 'Resource' the ID still starts at 1 instead of at 21. So I would like to let EF do the auto incrementation instead of writing it myself.